# Change columns in Azure DevOps backlog for everyone

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps I have created my **Dashboard** with all the **Work Items**.

[image]

Also, each user can customize the dashboard with adding/removing columns from the list. I like to change the list of column by default for everyone but I can't find how.

In the **Settings** section there is no options for it.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same question, and in absence of any other response looked a little further.

In Microsoft Docs, they indicate that this in not a behaviour they support.

**"You can't set column options for other members of your team, nor can you set default column options."**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/set-column-options?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

[image: About persistence of column options screenshot from Microsoft Docs page]